# Is there any type of list that will hold user info into second tab?

Tags: android, android-layout

In first tab, user will input some info about themselves and after submission, user info will be recorded to the second tab.Second tab will list all recorded users row by row.

I tried ListViews but it doesn't seem like what I'm exactly looking for. Because I don't want to clear second tab. I would like to hold all data that I submitted before. I just posted a part of first tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:id="@+id/tab1">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#9e3d7f"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittxt1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to learn how to make Customlistview then you should learn to use a JSON which have your information ,

Comment: I think there should be an eaiser way. We are just submitting "name,age,YearsOfExp.." info from user at first tab, in second tab we will list all recorded datas that we submitted previously

Comment: explain it will work online or offline ,simple listview just show one text so u need to create an activity for showing chosen item information like name and age and ...sure u need using JSON